# Jtable, use different alignment for each ROW

Tags: java, swing, jtable, alignment, tablecellrenderer

I have created a table and need to align every second row to the right, and every other row to default.

I understand how to align the rows. This is my default renderer

```
final DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER); 
final DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(DefaultTableCellRenderer.RIGHT);
```

Comment: for betteer help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to tweak the renderer a little and override its `getTableCellRendererComponent` method. Something like:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (r % 2 == 0) {
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        }
        else {
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }
};
```

Although creating your own proper class that extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and does this would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

See [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/).

This will allow you to change the alignment in one place even if your table uses multiple renderers and without creating a custom renderer.